# How can I change the MAC of outgoing ARP requests?

Tags: linux, arp

Is it possible to change the source MAC of all the outgoing ARP requests to a specific MAC instead of using the interface MAC in linux?

Is there a way to do this from the ARP tables?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this can be achieved by adding rules by `arptables`.

Use this rule:

```
arptables -A OUT --source-hw xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -j mangle --mangle-hw-s yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
```

You may also add more filtering options if you need example interface, subnet etc.

For more information, refer to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/arptables).